# How to set a background image in a static UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I tried the following code, but the cell doesn't change at all:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set background image of cells
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [CalculatorTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spots.png"]];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things. First of all, cells should be created in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Secondly, you should make your background view and then add it to the cell content view.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   cell = [CalculatorTableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil]; //This wil obviously depend on your subclass
   UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Spots.png"]];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"Spots.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ]autorelease];
```

That might be a better way to do it.

OR, you can try this:

You can try this code that will help you.

Put this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
   UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 277, 58)];
    av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    av.opaque = NO;
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Spots.png"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;
```

You put your cell initializing code in viewDidLoad? That is very wrong, it should be in:

```
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

You might want to check out this link:

[TableView programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: I am using iOS5 and my cells are created statically directly from the storyboard, therefore I am not using the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and unfortunately the solutions above do not apply...

Comment: I found it, for static cells, just need to set the background to "Clear Color" in the attributes inspector. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Cells created using static table views don't exist until after `viewWillAppear:` has been called. Move your code above into that method (and make sure you call the `super` implementation first.

Comment: Hi jrurton, you are right, I haven't tried that but I will test. The other option I found is to control drag the cells into my implementation file and control the behavior of the static cell as I wish. Many thanks all for the help.